# Clean URLS/.htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, drupal-7, clean-urls

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA
```

Looking for feedback

Goal: I am trying to enable "Clean URLs" on a Drupal 7 site (such that example.com/?q=user resolves to example.com/user).

I've just spent way too long pouring through official Drupal docs and comments, to no avail, so any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

I have checked the box "Enable Clean URLs" in Drupal (/admin/config/search/clean-urls) and got the all-clear that the configuration options were saved. So now I am actually able to go to example.com/user and it does indeed display the same content as example.com/?q=user. What I want, however, is for example.com/?q=user to be rewritten in the URI as example.com/user.

The relevant .htaccess code is shown above, and my Apache conf appears to be properly configured.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clean urls do indeed work but I kept getting errors until I found this
This saved my sanity:

- disable Overlay module
- go to Clean URLS
- change URL from: /?q=admin/config/search/clean-urls
- to: /admin/config/search/clean-urls
- Then the Check box should appear

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for this issue, the solution that work for me was that:

1. Left click on the wamp server icon and go to the apache.
2. Here sub menu will be opened, go to the apache modules and enable the rewrite_module.
3. now restart wamp server and then check your site.
4. Enable clean url will now be active.

Answer (score 0):

there should be a closing bracket on your last line "]". Perhaps this is the source of your frustration?